# Build custom capacitor and measure charge

Tags: capacitor, charge

My goal is to charge small metal ball/cylinder (steel ball - roughly 1 cm in diameter) to the maximum possible capacity.

One way to do it is to build a custom capacitor with metal ball being one of the electrodes.

I am curious how can I measure charge on this ball? The only thing that comes to my mind is to monitor current while charging and take into account resistance. Are there simpler ways to accomplish it?

Comment: (measuring the capacitance is equivalent to measuring charge – Capacitance is charge per voltage, so if you know the capacitance, you can define how much charge it has by charging it to a voltage.)

Comment: Capacitance is a physical property... the larger your ball is, the more capacitance it will have.  And the interior can be hollow.

Comment: You didn't say what your other electrode was. But, unless it is another concentric sphere inside or outside with a very close separation, your capacitance will be very small, almost too small to measure. If you want to demonstrate capacitance and charge, use a plate capacitor instead. Make one with aluminum foil and a paper electrolyte. Weight the sandwich down with books to minimize the air gap.

Comment: @Mattman944, thank you! I am not yet sure of the shape of electrode. I do want it to have high capacitance, but it also must be a bit rigid, so foil probably would not work, but an aluminum plate will.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to measure the charge, in coulombs, would be to calculate it by measuring the capacitance of the object (or by [calculating the capacitance](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/capsph.html), given the object's size, proximity to ground and the air's dielectric constant), and measuring the voltage.

Use an [electrostatic voltmeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_voltmeter) to measure the potential on the sphere, and from that, calculate the charge.

If accuracy is not as important as doing this yourself, make an [electroscope](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3qyeQO1guKk) and calibrate as a DIY electrostatic voltmeter.

BTW, in air at STP, between rounded surfaces, the [breakdown voltage is ~1 to 3 kV/mm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_breakdown). A 1 cm spark to ground indicates roughly 10,000 to 30,000 volts.